# vertically center a button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, margin, vertical-alignment

Im trying to center the `<form>` tag that contains the `<button>`

**what my View looks like:**

- `<p>` tag and the '' are in flex.
- `<p>` tag is aligned in the center vertically
- the button is laying at the bottom

**what I tried:**

- `class="align-middle"` in the `<form>`

I know I could set pixel bottom margin but that seems like a sloppy way to code it since if i wanted to later add or remove to the `<p>` I would have to come back and re-adjust the margin

---

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <p>some random text placeholder</p>

    <form class="align-items-center" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-ParticipantId="@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantId" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-5 bg-light">remove</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**using bootstrap 4.6**

Comment: Bootstrap has the class `justify-content-center` class which you could apply to the form. [Bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

Comment: i tried that by surrounding the `<form>` with a `<div class="justify-content-center">` but it changed nothing. also tried `<div class="d-flex align-items-center">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-v4-rtl/4.6.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <span class="d-flex align-items-center">some random text placeholder</span>

    <form class="" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-ParticipantId="@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantId" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger bg-light">remove</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-v4-rtl/4.6.0-2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the `<p>` and the button should be next to each other horizontally. and the button needs to be centered and not lingering at the bottom vertically.

Comment: actually you should align-center  p not button and p element will get a margin bottom by default so you can margin-0 p element or use span instead then align center it